# Open multiple urls from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I can open one chrome window through

```
open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

I can also open multiple URLs by multiple lines

```
open https://www.youtube.com/
open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

The following won't work though

```
open https://www.youtube.com/ && https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

but it works with

```
open https://www.youtube.com/ && open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

I want an elegant inline expression like

```
open ('https://www.youtube.com/','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you’re using the default `bash` shell:

```
for fff in $(echo https://one.com/whatever http://two.com/something%20else )
do
    open $fff
done
```

You don’t necessarily need the $(echo a b c) and could just paste in the words. You can also skip the multiple lines with two semicolons where needed to split the **for** loop:

```
for fff in a b c; do echo $fff; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Just supply all of the URLs you want to open as arguments to a single `open` command:

```
open https://www.youtube.com/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

The `open` command has been written to handle this.

The reason it doesn't work with `&&` is that in shell syntax, `&&` is a delimiter between different commands, not between arguments to the same command. So it was trying to run `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page` as a separate command, which doesn't work.

More specifically, `&&` runs the second command only if the first command succeeds. There are a number of command delimiters you can use with different meanings:

```
cmd1 ; cmd2    # Runs cmd1 and then cmd2 (just as though they were on different lines)
cmd1 & cmd2    # Runs cmd1 and cmd2 simultaneously, with cmd1 in the background
cmd1 | cmd2    # Runs cmd1 and cmd2 simultaneously, with cmd1's output piped to cmd2's input
cmd1 && cmd2    # Runs cmd1, and then if it succeeds runs cmd2
cmd1 || cmd2    # Runs cmd1, and then if it fails runs cmd2
```